# Exclude a particular schema from code generation in JOOQ

Tags: java, orm, code-generation, jooq

I've currently trying to generate classes based on my existing Postgres DB using JOOQ. In my JOOQ .xml config **I have left out any inputSchema tags** so that JOOQ generates all the schemas it finds:

```
     <schemata>
      <schema>
      </schema>
     </schemata>
```

However, I would like to exclude the **information schema** from the content that gets generated. Is there a way to do this in black list way? Or do I have to add input schemas for all the schemas except information schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `<excludes>` configuration as documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration

```xml
<includes>.*</includes>
<excludes>
  (?i:information_schema\..*) # I'm using (?i: ... ) for case-insensitivity here...
</excludes>
```

Both `<includes>` and `<excludes>` take Java regular expressions as arguments, which make matching unwanted schemas relatively easy.